# preg_replace delimiters with HTML tags

Tags: php, preg-replace, delimiter

I would like to use some kind of BB code for a php application: If you are writing text between two "slashdots" (example: `To /.be/. or /.not/. to be!`) it will appear *italic*.
I'm currently using the following pattern:

```
preg_replace('/\/\.(.*)\/\./', '<i>$1</i>', $text)
```

but it would return `To <i>be/. or /.not</i> to be!` for that example instead of `To <i>be</i> or <i>not</i> to be!`...

I also tried with *negative look-ahead assertion*, but it throws errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non-greedy match (question mark):

```
preg_replace('/\/\.(.*?)\/\./', '<i>$1</i>', $text);
```